# How to plot the peak of a wavefunction depending on time

Tags: numerics, mathematical-optimization

I am trying to define a function to find the spatial peak of some interpolation function of two variables (one spatial variable and one temporal variable) which is the output of `NDSolve`. In order to keep this question simple, let me use this Interpolation function instead:

```
list = Flatten[Table[{x, t, Cos[x + t]}, {x, 0, 10}, {t, 0, 10}], 1];
prob = Interpolation[list]
```

I tried the following:

```
peak[t_?NumericQ, func_] := 
 x /. Last[NMaximize[{func[x, t], 0 < x < 10}, x]]
```

where `func_` stands for the interpolation function for which I want to find the peak and `x` and `t` are the spatial and temporal variables, respectively. I try to plot that for the interpolating function `prob[x,t]`:

```
Plot[peak[t, prob], {t, 0, 10}]
```

However, the output appears after a long time. Is there a way to optimize that? Can I define the function of the peak differently in order to get a faster plot?

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Maybe you can find peak in your original NDSolve  directly.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your function it is obvious that it does not have an unique maximum. "prob" has a maximum along the lines: `x+t == 2 n Pi` where n is an integer.

Therefore, for an example, I choose a function with an unique maximum:

```
list = Flatten[
   Table[{x, t, Exp[-(x - 5)^2 - (t - 5)^2]}, {x, 0, 10}, {t, 0, 10}],
    1];
prob = Interpolation[list]
sol = NMaximize[{prob[x, t], 0 < x < 5, 0 <= t <= 5}, {x, t}]
Show[{Plot3D[prob[x, t], {x, 0, 10}, {t, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All], 
  Graphics3D[{PointSize[Large], Black, 
    Point[{x, t, sol[[1]]} /. sol[[2]]]}]}]
```

[image]

**Update**

To get the maximum as a function of time we may define the function "max[t]". As "max" is time consuming I make an example with "Manipulate" and draw only one point as a function of time:

```
list = Flatten[
   Table[{x, t, Exp[-0.1 (x - 5)^2 - 0.1 (t - 5)^2]}, {x, 0, 10}, {t, 
     0, 10}], 1];
prob = Interpolation[list]
sol[t_] := NMaximize[{prob[x, t], 0 < x < 10}, x][[2]];
max[t_] := {x /. sol[t], t, prob[x /. sol[t], t]}


Manipulate[
 Show[{ListPlot3D[list, PlotRange -> All],
   ParametricPlot3D[{x, t, prob[x, t]}, {x, 0, 10}],
   Graphics3D[{PointSize[0.04], Point[max[t]]}]
   }]
 , {t, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! That's right, I didn't notice that. My trouble is, however, that I want a function that describes which is the position of the peak at each instant of time. I'm searching for something like peak[t], that I could apply to different functions function[x,t] and then plot the value of the peak for each time instant.